# How to replace text in anchor tag in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a anchor tag

```
 <a class="bx-prev" href="">Prev</a>
```

Now I want replace text "Prev" with

```
     <i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

How to do it in jquery?

Comment: This is poor research. jQuery docs is the place for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["jQuery way" to replace just a text node with a mix of HTML and text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851702/jquery-way-to-replace-just-a-text-node-with-a-mix-of-html-and-text)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this script, it'll work surely;

`<a class="bx-prev" href="">Prev</a>`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.bx-prev').click(function(){
 $('.bx-prev').html('<i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
 return false;
});

});
```